# What library should I use for JsonFormatter?

Tags: c#, json

I am using using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json; but still can not use jsonFormatter in my code. I also can not find System.Json in my references. 
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to format JSON, just include Newtonsoft.Json library and use SerializeObject...

```
var formattedStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strToFormat, Formatting.Indented);
```